# configure git to show untracked files for a specific directory

Tags: git

I'm using the [arch wikis suggestion](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dotfiles) to version `$HOME` config files.

The gist is to not show untracked files via:

```sh
git init --bare ~/.dotfiles
alias config='/usr/bin/git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles/ --work-tree=$HOME'
config config status.showUntrackedFiles no
```

This works fine.

Can I configure git to always show **all** untracked files in e.g. `$HOME/important`?

Comment: No. The only control knobs available are "all", "no", and the default compressed variant; there's no selection based on the path.

Comment: `git status -s -uall | grep  -E '^\?\? important/'` ?